# Deploying Sanic Raw

Tags: python, deployment, sanic

[Sanic](https://github.com/channelcat/sanic) appears to be a highly perfomant web framework (server) for Python. From experience with other frameworks, including Flask and Django I know that it is generally recommended to put the Python server behind another server (e.g. reverse Proxy) like Nginx for security reasons. How does that translate to Sanic, or a gunicorn server running Sanic? Does someone have experience with that. I wonder if it is safe to expose a Python server to the web.

Comment: Could you point me to a resource elaborating on the security issues? When I put an Nginx in front of my Python apps, it's usually in order to wrap the traffic in TLS or to serve static content efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't deployed sanic to a prod environment yet, but previous deploys followed the following logic:

Internet <-> Nginx <-> Uwsgi (or gunicorn) <-> python framework (django or other framework)

According to this [Deploy Sanic](https://github.com/channelcat/sanic/blob/master/docs/sanic/deploying.md) you can launch sanic with multiple workers and behind gunicorn.

So I am guessing nginx <-> gunicorn <-> gunicorn myapp:app --bind 0.0.0.0:8080 --worker-class sanic.worker.GunicornWorker